# Why doesn't the MongoDb Atlas UI let me insert an array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am learning MongoDb and I trying to insert an object, through the MongoDb Atlas UI, that contains a `members` array which is an array of objects `[{x: 1}]`. The UI lets me set `members` as an array of numbers, e.g `[1,2 ]`, but it won't let me set it to `[{x: 1}]`. Any idea why?

Object:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60f5f833e3a6791569997478"
    },
    "members":  [{x: 1}]
}
```

It says: `Insert not permitted while document contains errors.`

UI:

[image]

Comment: Does the `x` also need to be enclosed in double-quotes?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts I am feeling very dumb now. Thank you very much. If you would like to answer the question I would accept it.

Comment: No problem, I've been there before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of fields need to be enclosed in quotes, so the correct formatting for the object would be:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60f5f833e3a6791569997478"
    },
    "members":  [{"x": 1}]
}
```